# How do I accurately slice images in Illustrator CS3?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, slices

I have just finished building a new web page in HTML 5 and using a jQuery slider effect to horizontally scroll across the web pages.

Now I need to design a background at 8000x1000px so it all "flows and connects" perfectly between each seperate background image.  To do this, I need to divide this large 8000px image into 4 separate 2000px background files.

How can I create 4 images from 1 source file using Illustrator (currently using CS3) that will stitch seamlessly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google of "illustrator CS3 slice" turns up [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Illustrator/13.0/help.html?content=WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6369.html) from the Adobe forum:

> Place guides where you want to slice the artwork, and choose Object > Slice > Create From Guides.

At which point you Save For Web.

Comment: Thanks I was playing with the tile option but couldnt get it to work, will try this way. Cheers